# To see anonymous function declaration

Tags: scala

If I have a code:

`map foreach {  case(k,v) => println("k="+k+";v="+v)` }

How may I make sure which kind of anonymous function foreach() function is accepting ? I mean what kind of declaration was used to define this function?

I'm guessing it is: `Tuple2[Int, String] => Unit`

But how may I see it / be sure ? In a console.

Comment: You might try `scala -Xprint:all`, but it's pretty verbose.

Comment: @James `Xprint:typer` is slightly verbose, but it's not hard to see `private[this] val res0: Unit = $line3.$read.$iw.$iw.m.foreach[Int](((x0$1: (Int, String)) => x0$1 match {`. That's with `case (k,v) => k` to show `U` is solved as `Int`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:t` inside the REPL

```
scala> val m = Map((1, "a"))
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a)

scala> :t m.foreach _
(((Int, String)) => Any) => Unit
```

This gives you the type of `foreach`, and you can see it takes `(Int, String)) => Any`.

Comment: @som-snytt We throw away the return value of the function, so why would you constrain it? And the result of `:t m.foreach[Int] _` is frankly wrong for most invocations of `foreach`